# HC-05 voltage divider

Tags: arduino-nano, hc-05

I am currently testing a small Arduino Nano project (schematic below) and have encountered issues when communicating between a HC-05 Bluetooth module and the Arduino. I am using a simple LED bulb which I am trying to turn on and off from a phone which is connected to the HC-05. The HC-05 is powered separately by some batteries instead of being powered by the Arduino itself. The Bluetooth connection is functional, and so is the actual LED functionality on the Arduino, but there seems to be a problem when I am trying to send stuff through the RX/TX connection. I previously attempted this without a voltage divider and had the same problem. Am I using the right resistors for the voltage divider or should I step them up to 1k and 2k respectively? I measured the voltage on the RX/TX and for some reason it only amounts to around 1.5V (instead of the desired 3.3V). Is there any other issue I am not seeing?

[image]

Edit: I also measured the voltage on the RX/TX without the voltage divider and somehow it's straight up 0. Why would that be?

Comment: connect the grounds together

Comment: both the 200 ohm resistor branch and the HC-05 GND are connected to the cathode of my batteries

Comment: What about the ground of the Arduino...?

Comment: Arduino is plugged in (via mini USB)

Comment: Connect the grounds of the 2 boards together, like jsotola said!